# iOS: issues using variables inside MACRO

Tags: ios, macros, compiler-warnings, unused-variables

Can anyone please tell me why following Warns me "unused variable variable str"?  SetAccessibilityLabelForView is a MACRO.

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:dynString, index];
SetAccessibilityLabelForView(myView, str);
```

dynamicString is setup in singleton class like `"dynamic%d"`.

Macro:

```
#if RUN_TESTS
#define SetAccessibilityLabelForView(view, label) view.accessibilityLabel = label
#else
#define SetAccessibilityLabelForView(view, label)
#endif
```

WARNING comes for both the cases when RUN_TESTS true or false but if I removed else part then Warning goes away!

I have tried using following to get rid of warning,

```
  SetAccessibilityLabelForView(myView, [NSString stringWithFormat:dynString, index])
```

that gives me ERROR: "Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation"!

Then I have changed my macro to following,

```
#if RUN_TESTS
#define SetAccessibilityLabelForView(view, label, ...) view.accessibilityLabel = label
#else
#define SetAccessibilityLabelForView(view, label, ...)
#endif
```

Now same line works when RUN_TESTS FALSE but gives error "Expected ']'" when RUN_TESTS is TRUE!! Phew!!

Can someone please help me here. I want to get macro working for both the cases but just want to ignore lines generated by macro when RUN_TESTS is FALSE.

Comment: Post the macro code please

Comment: I would be surprised if warning because of macro but anyway I edited question.

Comment: I am surprised :) I think it comes because in else option I am not using "label"! Can I get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't resolve this issue! I am ended up ignoring unsused variable warning like below.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:dynString, index];
SetAccessibilityLabelForView(myView, str);

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

[EDIT]

Finally I came out with better solution writting another macro to support formatted string..

```
#if RUN_TESTS
#define SetAccessibilityFormatedLabelForView(view, labelFormat, ...) view.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:labelFormat, __VA_ARGS__]
#else
#define SetAccessibilityFormatedLabelForView(view, labelFormat, ...)
#endif
```

Usage:

```
SetAccessibilityFormatedLabelForView(myView, dynString, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is going wrong because if RUN_TESTS is not defined, then the code:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:dynString, index];
SetAccessibilityLabelForView(myView, str);
```

gets expanded to:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: dynString, index];
-blank-
```

Try doing this instead (with the first version of the macro):

```
SetAccessibilityLabelForView(myView, [NSString stringWithFormat: dynString, index]);
```

This gets expanded to this if RUN_TESTS is defined:

```
myView.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat: dynString, index];
```

or just completely compiled out if it isn't (so should build fine in both cases).

Comment: You right but I want to get it working for both the cases when RUN_TESTS defined or not. Please see updated question. Thanks.

Comment: This should work even with that defined. The point is that you have a variable that isn't being used but is being referenced in the non-running-tests state. All you need to do is shift that into the actual macro.

Comment: I did that but it gives me  ERROR: "Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation"! for first version..